# `or al, al` in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
print_string:
   lodsb        ; grab a byte from SI
   cmp al, 0
   ;or al, al  ; logical or AL by itself
   jz .done   ; if the result is zero, get out

   mov ah, 0x0E
   int 0x10h
```

I'm wondering how `or al, al` works. I know that it tests to see if all of the characters in the string have been printed out? But I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Related: `test al,al` would be a better choice: [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](//stackoverflow.com/a/33724806)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If al is 0 (or rather, the result of `or al, al` is 0, which only happens when al is 0), then it sets the zero flag. The jump (jz), tests the zero flag and jumps if it is set.

Comment: in that case why don't use `test al, al`?

Comment: It would work. I guess it doesn't really matter. There are often may ways to do the same thing in assembly.

Comment: Some people prefer `OR`, some `AND` or `TEST`. IMO, `test` is the instruction that have to be used for checking for zero. It is defined with this goal in mind.

Comment: For performance reasons, `test al,al` is never worse, and often better (except in rare corner cases on now-obsolete P6-family (Intel PPro through Nehalem), to avoid register-read stalls, where modifying a register for no reason can actually be useful, despite introducing extra latency into the dep chain).  [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33721204)

Answer (score 2):

`or al, al` sets the zero flag if the result is 0 (i.e. when al = 0), just as `cmp al, 0` does.  The useful difference between the two operations is that `or al, al` has a smaller encoding on x86 architectures.